# Limit Number using Javascript or RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

can anyone help me on how could I do on javascript or regEx to limit whole number into 12 with 2 decimal places so that inputs on textbox will be validated?

E.G

```
999999999999.99 - valid
99999999.999 - invalid
1234584.58 -valid
1.99 - valid
1000000000000 - invalid
```

Comment: Do you want a Regex that either matches or doesn't match, or are you looking to transform invalid numbers?

Comment: i want RegEx that match numbers with 12 integers or below and with/without 2 numbers as decimal places

Answer (score 5):

You can use the regex;

```
^[0-9]{1,12}\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: may i know on how could I implement it on input type="text" (textbox)??

Answer (score 1):

The one given is wrong : it wont validate 12 digits

```
^[0-9]{1,12}\.[0-9]{2}$
```

```
1920304049.09 // OK
192030404985  // not ok
1.34          // ok
33.98         // ok
33.9          // not ok
```

The following will

```
^(\d{1,12})(\.\d\d)?$
```

```
1920304049.09 // OK
192030404985  // ok
1.34          // ok
33.98         // ok
33.9          // not ok
```

Comment: Plus, the former one will not validate number without decimals either because the dot and decimal digits are compulsory ...

Comment: okey then, tell me exactly what should match and what souldn't : I will give you the regexp

Comment: it should be

123456789123.12 - okay
958.1 - okay
1578463499915 - not (13 numbers)
5487564.325 - not (3 decimals)
54843. - not (will also validated because no decimal number but have decimal point
112457844.12 - okay
12.12 - okay
512.00 - okay

Comment: simply add an question mark after the second digit meta character like this `(\.\d\d?)?` (only one decimal is now valid)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it and it works perfectly. the below is the regex and the test data

```
^[0-9]{1,12}((\.[0-9]{1,2})|)$

123456789123.12 - okay
958.1 - okay
1578463499915 - not (13 numbers)
1548745654485.125 - not (13 numbers and 3 decimals)
5487564.325 - not (3 decimals)
54843. - not (will also validated because no decimal number but have decimal point
112457844.12 - okay
12.12 - okay
512.00 - okay
25867s56.5 - not (have letter)
654.01 - okay
1 - okay
01 - okay
00048 - okay
```

Comment: `((\.[0-9]{1,2})|)` is equal to `(\.\d\d?)?` but the latter is 'more readable'

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex.

```
function check(string){

var list = string.split('.');

if(parseInt(string[0], 10) > 0 && parseInt(string[1], 10) > 0){
if(list.length != 2){
    return false;
}
else if(list[0].length <= 12 && list[1].length <= 2){
    return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
} else{
return false;
}
}

if(check(1000000000000) == true){
    alert('valid');
}
else{
    alert('invalid');
}
```

I didn't test it, but it should work.